# A customer bad payer who hosts the wordpress database and files: how to stay admin of the system?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I do have a big issue with one of my customers, who doesn't pay for the job.

The wordpress files and database are on his server. I'm still able to manage those elements (via ftp, wordpress admin) but it will not last forever :-|

My questions :

- Is there a simple way to ensure that only my admin account can be
  used, at least to delay his taking over the system, which is of
  course inevitable : A double admin authentication, with a second
  password asked, grabbed from another page than wp-config or sent to my
  e-mail?
- Anything else, not too complicated to implement?

Thank you by advance for your precious help.

Comment: No for both, once he owns the files he can do with it whatever he wants. To ensure, you just have to take down the site until you get payed. When he has payed you upload the site again. Don't deliver anything to someone until he or she has payed you for the work.

Comment: Thank you Niels for your answer. It was a bit more complicated: a big project with several advances paid, etc. I know that my customer will do whatever he wants with the files and the database, but the idea was to make things more difficult for him, to delay his taking over the website. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Then I would start with adding a .htaccess file which limits access to 'wp-admin' to your IP only.

Comment: Anything to propose within the wordpress files? He seems to know pretty well the htaccess file, much better than wordpress. Thank you!